# "cfx test" fails after setting up Firefox add-on environment

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to develop a Firefox add on.

Following the Mozilla instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started), I've installed and activated their SDK.

I then created a new directory, `cd`'d to it, and ran `cd init` to initialize it.  The output was:

> - lib directory created
> - data directory created
> - test directory created
> - generated jID automatically: jid1-lobtqQKBC2PgyA
> - package.json written
> - test/test-main.js written
> - lib/main.js written
>
> Your sample add-on is now ready.
>   Do "cfx test" to test it and "cfx run" to try it.  Have fun!

So far, so good (although the output wasn't exactly like their example).  I then try running: `cfx test`, and I get the following:

```
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
Running tests on Firefox 34.0/Gecko 34.0 ({ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}) under winnt/x86.
.console.error: x:
  fail:
  There was an uncaught Promise rejection: JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Prom
ise-backend.js :: PendingErrors.register :: line 159
JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js :: this.PromiseWalker.comple
tePromise :: line 672
JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js :: Handler.prototype.process
 :: line 868
JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js :: this.PromiseWalker.walker
Loop :: line 744
native frame :: <unknown filename> :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 0
console.trace: x:
_ecated/unit-test.js 96 fail
_ecated/unit-test.js 61 TestRunner.prototype._uncaughtErrorObserver
_/Promise-backend.js 197 PendingErrors.report
_/Promise-backend.js 209 PendingErrors.flush
_/Promise-backend.js 611 Promise.Debugging.flushUncaughtErrors
_ecated/unit-test.js 306 done
_ecated/unit-test.js 529 start
_ecated/unit-test.js 491 runNextTest
_ecated/unit-test.js 496 startMany
_ecated/unit-test.js 26 findAndRunTests/<
_/Promise-backend.js 865 Handler.prototype.process
_/Promise-backend.js 744 this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop
                     0

.
2 of 3 tests passed.
LdrLoadDll: Blocking load of 'hook.dll' -- see http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/blocklist/
Total time: 1.816000 seconds
Program terminated unsuccessfully.
```

I'm not really sure what this hook.dll file is, why it's failing, or what the relationship to Mozilla's block list is (couldn't find it on that page).

Any help or insight to resolve this error would be appreciated.  I'm on a Windows 7 Pro, 64bit OS if that helps.